# VBA: ReDimming multiple keyed collections = Error 9 'Subscript Out of Range'?

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to modify some keyed collection code (thanks @Mat'sMug!) to make it loop through 3 distinct ranges and then put the values into respective variables. The first keyed collection works fine, but the second one (and I'm guessing the third once it gets past the second) spit an error out at the line `ReDim ccAddresses(0 To ccRecipients.Count - 1)`

```
Private Sub AddUniqueItemToCollectionzz(ByVal value As String, ByVal items As Collection)
    On Error Resume Next
    items.Add value, Key:=value
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub Sampletest()
    Dim toRecipients As Collection
    Set toRecipients = New Collection
    Dim ccRecipients As Collection
    Set ccRecipients = New Collection
    Dim cc2Recipients As Collection
    Set cc2Recipients = New Collection


    '===============Copy primary email addresses=============
    With toRecipients
        For Each cell In Range("H1:H350")
            If cell.value Like "*@*.*" Then
                AddUniqueItemToCollectionzz cell, toRecipients
            End If
        Next
    End With

    ReDim toAddresses(0 To toRecipients.Count - 1)

    Dim toAddress As Variant, toItem As Long
    For Each toAddress In toRecipients
        toAddresses(toItem) = CStr(toAddress)
        toItem = toItem + 1
    Next

    Dim sendToPrim As String
    sendToPrim = Join(toAddresses, ";")

    '=====================Copy cc email addresses======================
    With ccRecipients
        For Each cell In Range("J1:J350")
            If cell.value Like "*@*.**" Then
                AddUniqueItemToCollectionzz cell, ccRecipients
            End If
        Next
    End With

    ReDim ccAddresses(0 To ccRecipients.Count - 1)

    Dim ccAddress As Variant, ccItem As Long
    For Each ccAddress In ccRecipients
        ccAddresses(ccItem) = CStr(ccAddress)
        ccItem = ccItem + 1
    Next

    Dim sendToCC As String
    sendToCC = Join(ccAddresses, ";")

    '====================Copy cc2 email addresses================
    With cc2Recipients
        For Each cell In Range("A1:a350")
            If cell.value Like "*.uSA.TACO*" Then
                AddUniqueItemToCollectionzz cell, cc2Recipients
            End If
        Next
    End With

    ReDim cc2Addresses(0 To cc2Recipients.Count - 1)

    Dim cc2Address As Variant, cc2Item As Long
    For Each ccAddress In cc2Recipients
        cc2Addresses(cc2Item) = CStr(cc2Address)
        cc2Item = cc2Item + 1
    Next

    Dim sendToCC2 As String
    sendToCC2 = Join(cc2Addresses, ";")
```

Comment: What is `cc2Recipients` when that gets called? I don't see where you set it to anything, or add to the collection first.  Put `debug.print cc2Recipients.count` before that line, it should either error out or return `0`.

Comment: @BruceWayne Solved. Please see updates above.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Done. Also bookmarked your site. Dope!

Comment: Don't update the question to include the answer. Write an *answer* instead. I've rolled back that last edit.

Comment: Does it matter that there are going to be possible email addresses that are present in all three collections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dimensioning or redimensioning with `Dim(x to y)` or `ReDim(x to y)` `y` must be greater than or equal to  `x`.  So check your code by adding following line before the `ReDim ccAddresses(0 To ccRecipients.Count - 1)` statement.

```
Debug.Assert ccRecipients.Count >0
```